# Python Sklearn train_test_split(): how to set Which Data is Taken for Training?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For the following scikit-learn function: [`train_test_split()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

Is it possible to tell the function ***where*** to set the split of the data?

Or in other words:

Can I tell the function that `X_train, X_test` should be on the left or right side from the split point and that `y_train, y_test` should be on the right side?

(and does the splitting really work this way - or are just arbitrary rows of the input data taken until the split ratio is obeyed?)

If it is not possible to tell the function which data should be taken for training and testing: is there any equivalent alternative that is usable for this use case?

Comment: You don't wanna have biased test set, it is best to do a random test train split, infact testing on multiple test sets (also called k fold cross validation) maybe better depending on training algorithm and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using KFold would look like:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X = np.arange(20).reshape((10, 2))
y = np.arange(20)

print(X)
print(y)
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN size: {0:5d} from: {1:5d} to: {2:5d}".format(train_index.size, train_index[0], train_index[train_index.size - 1]))
    print("TEST  size: {0:5d} from: {1:5d} to: {2:5d}".format(test_index.size, test_index[0], test_index[test_index.size - 1]))
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

results in:

```
 [[ 0  1]
 [ 2  3]
 [ 4  5]
 [ 6  7]
 [ 8  9]
 [10 11]
 [12 13]
 [14 15]
 [16 17]
 [18 19]]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     1 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     0 to:     0
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     1 to:     1
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     2 to:     2
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     3 to:     3
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     4 to:     4
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     5 to:     5
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     6 to:     6
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     7 to:     7
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     9
TEST  size:     1 from:     8 to:     8
--
TRAIN size:     9 from:     0 to:     8
TEST  size:     1 from:     9 to:     9
```

Answer (score 5):

From Scikit Learn documentation:
Split arrays or matrices into **random** train and test subsets..

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
>>> X
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
...
>>> X_train
array([[4, 5],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
>>> y_train
[2, 0, 3]
>>> X_test
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])
>>> y_test
[1, 4]
```

also you can turn off shuffling:

```
>>> train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
```